# Resize of the front when using SideNav - Materialize

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I'm making a website with Symfony and Materialize, and my client wants to have the menu on the side. I used the documentation http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html to make it, and managed to make the side menu on the left. But I have now two problems:

- first, not important, when I press alt on Firefox, it makes the windows resize a little by making the top menu appears, and the side menu goes from left to right. It's kinda annoying, but not that important.
- second, the content under the side menu is hidden, and doesn't resize to make everything appears. I tried to make a div and put in the css a margin-left, but it didn't work.

Here is my code html:

```
<nav>
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
  <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a></nav>
```

And here is the js:

```
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
  menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
  edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
  closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
});

 $('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

It's only the code in the documentation, and I just have these problems. If anyone has a solution, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question: did you offset the non-side-nav content when the side-nav is open? Something like this:

```
  #app-body{
      padding-left: 320px;

      @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
       padding-left: 10px;
      }
    }
```

This ensures that on large screens, my content is offset by 320px (which is the width of my sideNav, but the when  sideNav is closed (when the screen is under 992px wide), the padding is removed.